# enhance performance for heavy image zoom in fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to have a function for my activeObject in which I can zoom on photo. 
I tried the code below , but the problem is that it takes about 5 seconds to do that.
how can I increase the performance for zooming and reduce this time.

```
zoomBy: function (x, y, z, canvasFabric, callback) {

            debugger;

            if (x || y) { this.zoomedXY = true; }
            this.cx += x;
            this.cy += y;

            if (z) {
                this.cw -= z;
                this.ch -= z / (this.width / this.height);
            }

            if (z && !this.zoomedXY) {
                // Zoom to center of image initially
                this.cx = this.width / 2 - (this.cw / 2);
                this.cy = this.height / 2 - (this.ch / 2);
            }

            if (this.cw > this.width) { this.cw = this.width; }
            if (this.ch > this.height) { this.ch = this.height; }
            if (this.cw < 1) { this.cw = 1; }
            if (this.ch < 1) { this.ch = 1; }
            if (this.cx < 0) { this.cx = 0; }
            if (this.cy < 0) { this.cy = 0; }
            if (this.cx > this.width - this.cw) { this.cx = this.width - this.cw; }
            if (this.cy > this.height - this.ch) { this.cy = this.height - this.ch; }

            this.rerender(canvasFabric, callback);
        },

        rerender: function (canvasFabric, callback) {

            var img = new Image(), obj = this;
            img.onload = function () {

                debugger;

                var canvas = fabric.util.createCanvasElement();

                canvas.width = obj.width;
                canvas.height = obj.height;
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, obj.cx, obj.cy, obj.cw, obj.ch, 0, 0, obj.width, obj.height);

                img.onload = function () {
                    obj.setElement(this);
                    obj.applyFilters(canvasFabric.renderAll.bind(canvasFabric));
                    obj.set({
                        left: obj.left,
                        top: obj.top,
                        angle: obj.angle
                    });
                    obj.setCoords();
                    if (callback) { callback(obj); }
                };
                debugger;
                img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            };
            debugger;
            img.src = this.orgSrc;
        },
```

I saw some others have this problem , but couldn't find any solution for this.
of course there is an answer [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3755)
but I have no Idea how to use it

Comment: for me is unclear what the desired effect it. What does it mean to zoom on foto?

Comment: I mean scale photo with fixed boundaries @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: Hard to help in this situation. Try to make a working stackoveflow snippet or a jsfiddle at least

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I created a fiddle for you, it's made by a high quality image , you can't see whole the picture , that's not important. but when you click on zoom in , you see screen is locked for seconds , zoom done and then you can do the rest. http://fiddle.jshell.net/FT7a9/434/

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi You can change your zoom function and try, what i did for me to zoom the photo, I changed the scale of photo and reset the cropX, cropY, height and width of the object so that container size will be same. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: @ManojLodhi Could you please update the fiddle for me with you answer?

Answer (score 0):

What i did for me to zoom the photo, I changed the scale of photo and reset the `cropX`, `cropY`, `height` and `width` of the object so that container size will be same. It works perfectly for me

You can try this, Remember i only made changes for zoom as you can see in your condition where you get the value of `z`. Also some change in HTML.

HTML

```
<button type="button" onclick="demo.zoomBy(0,0,0.01)">Zoom in</button>
<button type="button" onclick="demo.zoomBy(0,0,-0.01)">Zoom out</button>
```

JS

```
zoomBy: function(x, y, z, callback) 
{
    if (x || y) { this.zoomedXY = true; }
    this.cx += x;
    this.cy += y;

    if (z) {
        this.cw -= z;
        this.ch -= z/(this.width/this.height);
    }

    if (z && !this.zoomedXY) { 
        // Zoom to center of image initially
   console.info(this)
var origScale = this.scaleX;
 var currentScale = (origScale+z);
 var origWidth = this.cw, origHeight = this.ch;
            this.scaleX = currentScale;
            this.scaleY = currentScale;
            this.cx =  this.cx - (origWidth/(currentScale/origScale)-this.cw)/2;
            this.cy =  this.cy - (origHeight/(currentScale/origScale)-this.ch)/2;
            this.cw = origWidth/(currentScale/origScale);
            this.ch = origHeight/(currentScale/origScale);
        /* this.cx = this.width / 2 - (this.cw / 2);
        this.cy = this.height / 2 - (this.ch / 2); */
    }

    if (this.cw > this.width) { this.cw = this.width; }
    if (this.ch > this.height) { this.ch = this.height; }
    if (this.cw < 1) { this.cw = 1; }
    if (this.ch < 1) { this.ch = 1; }
    if (this.cx < 0) { this.cx = 0; }
    if (this.cy < 0) { this.cy = 0; }
    if (this.cx > this.width - this.cw) { this.cx = this.width - this.cw; }
    if (this.cy > this.height - this.ch) { this.cy = this.height - this.ch; }

    //this.rerender(callback);
this.canvas.renderAll();
},
```

Comment: this is changing the scale , I don't wanna change the scale , I just need to cropzoom